# Can't seem to get a JNDI JDBC resource working in Liferay

Tags: spring, jdbc, liferay, jndi

No joy in the Liferay forum on this issue and the clock is ticking on this project.  This may be caused by my lack of knowledge of Spring.

I have a JNDI global resource defined in server.xml and a resource link in context.xml in my Tomcat 7 /conf folder. I KNOW the JNDI resource is being loaded because I see the validation query being run as the server starts up. So far so good.

I have a portlet that just provides services to other portlets. In that portlet I have a hibernate.cfg.xml which has a session-factory that also points to the JDBC resource (don't know if this is needed or not). I also have an ext-spring.xml file in the services portlet that has the following:

```
<bean id="liferayHibernateSessionFactory" class="com.liferay.portal.spring.hibernate.PortletHibernateConfiguration" >
<property name="dataSource" ref="MyJDBCResource" />
</bean>

<bean id="MyJDBCResource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
<property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/MyJDBCResource" />
</bean>
```

Adding the above in ext-spring.xml fixed an issue with a bean error on that services portlet upon deployment. In that service builder built portlet, a services jar was created and I put that service jar in the Tomcat_Home/lib/ext folder so that I could use the services provided by the portlet in my portlet. So far so good. But, when I invoke the portlet method which calls the services provided by the other portlet with the JNDI references, I get a "user lacks privilege or object not found" error. It is *definitely* object not found. When the query is run I see absolutely NO activity on the JDBC connection specified by the JNDI resource entry and in drilling down on the connection properties I only see the HSQLDB driver in use. It *should* be using the MSSQL driver specified in my global resource JNDI entry as far as I understand it.

SO WHAT AM I DOING WRONG? Do I need to add some configuration entries in the portlet that *invokes* the services?

This seems so simple. In reading the many posts that give instructions on using JNDI/JDBC resources I seem to have followed them correctly. Is there some trick to using JNDI/JDBC resources in LR 6.1.1 and Tomcat 7 that I have missed?

Thanks (and really hoping for some answers!).

Answer (score 1):

First, you could try rewrite JNDI resource reference like this:

```
<bean id="MyJDBCResource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" >
  <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MyJDBCResource" />
</bean>
```

also, you could try different approach on JNDI resource lookup in Spring:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="MyJDBCResource" jndi-name="jdbc/MyJDBCResource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

Not sure about first approch, but second will definitively fail early in case no JNDI resource could be found.
Hope this helps.